# Jest - No tests found

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have specific situation. I have something like common module that define common behaviour of all integrations and all integrations is using that as a library. In that common module, I have configuration of jest and set of tests.

Everything works OK in case that common module is linked (`npm link`) to integration. But when this this common module is installed directly from npm, jest is not able to find any tests. I suppose, there are some files ignored, but I was not abe to find any configuration that would solve this situation.

Final configuration from `debug` mode looks like this:

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "/private/var/folders/mv/v_zhxfq113qf8d6vsf4ldwq80000gn/T/jest_dx",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "cwd": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration",
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "detectOpenHandles": false,
      "errorOnDeprecated": false,
      "extraGlobals": [],
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globals": {},
      "haste": {
        "computeSha1": false,
        "throwOnModuleCollision": false
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "node"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": [],
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "24eedccdafdba030f3d9209ab1064c8e",
      "prettierPath": "prettier",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/common_module/tests/api",
      "roots": [
        "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/common_module/tests/api"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
      "skipFilter": false,
      "slowTestThreshold": 5,
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/jest-environment-node/build/index.js",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testRegex": [],
      "testRunner": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/",
        "\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": 0,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [],
    "coverageDirectory": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/common_module/coverage",
    "coverageProvider": "babel",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "detectOpenHandles": false,
    "errorOnDeprecated": false,
    "expand": false,
    "findRelatedTests": false,
    "forceExit": false,
    "json": false,
    "lastCommit": false,
    "listTests": false,
    "logHeapUsage": false,
    "maxConcurrency": 5,
    "maxWorkers": 7,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "failure-change",
    "onlyChanged": false,
    "onlyFailures": false,
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "projects": [],
    "rootDir": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/common_module/tests/api",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "skipFilter": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testSequencer": "<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/@jest/test-sequencer/build/index.js",
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": true,
    "watch": false,
    "watchAll": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "26.4.0"
}
```

All tests are defined on path `<path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/common_module/tests/api` named as e.g. `something.test.js`.

Console will show allways:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in <path>/Workspace/integration/my_integration/node_modules/common_module/tests/api.
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html
Pattern:  - 0 matches
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```